# Does getAllDocumentsByKey work in lotus domino if there is a categorized column after the key columns?

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a notes View that has the first 5 columns categorized and the rest of them as flat.
For example:

1. company
2. user
3. year
4. month
5. day
6. project
7. hours
8. cost

I want to getAllDocumentsByKey (or getAllEntriesByKey) and my key is a vector of the first 4 columns. So i expect to get all documents for all days below month. Instead i get only the documents of the first category below month (those of day 1 only).

Finally i made a copy of the view with only the first 4 columns as categorized and i used this one to make it work, but is there any solution for this behavior?

Comment: out of curiosity, are you mixing types in your vector?  I think I once tested that all members had to be of the same type and the same type as the column contents in the background view.  I am not certain of this anymore as I did this over a year ago by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use a key to search multiple categories, pass a vector as the key.

```
java.util.Vector key = new Vector<String>() //could be Object

key.add("myCo");
key.add("user@myCo.com");
key.add("2012");
key.add("04");
key.add("1");

vw.getAllDocumentsByKey(key, false);
```

Comment: i already use this method, but i need the key to be till the month so as to get all docs for this month (for all days). the problem is that it returns only the docs of day 1.

Comment: your problem in that case is most likely the view columns not being set up to handle it.  I suggest 1. update your question to include the question you are going for.  2. Checking the formulas for your columns in the view to make use of strings/integers instead of simple @day(dateTime).  This can be problematic, give @Text(@Year(dateTime)) a try if you are not already doing this.

Comment: i ve already checked my columns' data types. They are all strings and not dates or integers. Please check this link, it describes my problem but doesnt give any clear solution.
http://ibm.co/WwFFVJ

Comment: Nope. As the forum entry says, there is no way to search 'a portion of' multiple categories. So either create an additional view, or use viewnavigator and scan all subcategories on a loop.